# Is GraphQL and SSO compatible?

Tags: single-sign-on, graphql

My project has plan to use SSO (maybe use Gluu or Auth0,...) and is also considering to apply GraphQL to our API.

On first look, it seem that these two should be easily compatible as they are working on different layers. But I still want to hear from someone experienced with both if there is any problems, considerations or guidelines when apply them to the project?

Answer (score 1):

GraphQL has no opinion in how you Authenticate or Authorize users. So you can use any auth you like.